# Smoothing a vector layer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vectorization

I extract riverbanks out of Landsat images at Google Earth Engine. After the vectorization of my raster image I receive a shapefile of the riverbank with many unwanted vertices. How can I smooth the vector layer? The vectorization code is:

```
// This function takes vectorized polygons and extracts a polyline
var simplifyAndExtractRiverbanks = function(vectors){
  // Simplify vectors
  var processedVectors = vectors.map(function(f) {
    var coords = f.geometry()
      .simplify({maxError: exportResolutionMeters})
      .coordinates();
    
    // Buffer the geometry by a pixel to avoid rasterizing the 
    //boundary polygon
    var bufferDistance = ee.Number(
      exportResolutionMeters).multiply(-1);
    return f
      .setGeometry(
        ee.Geometry.MultiLineString(coords)
          .intersection(geometry.buffer(bufferDistance)));
    });
    return processedVectors;

 var riverbankVector = simplifyAndExtractRiverbanks(vectors);

 // Export of shapefiles
   Export.table.toDrive({
     collection: riverbankVector,
     description: 'Extracted_Riverbank_Vector_2020',
     folder: 'earthengine',
     fileNamePrefix: 'riverbank2020',
     fileFormat: 'SHP'});
```

For the exportResolutionMeters I chose 30.

[image: This is the exported vector layer of the riverbank in QGIS with many steps and edges]